# connecting using a wired connection on linux doesn't work, but why?

Tags: networking

I have a dual boot machine, with windows xp and Fedora linux. Windows identifies the wired connection just well, but when I try to use the wired connection on Linux, it doesn't work.

When I inspect /var/log/messages, it says that "DHCP broadcast was not received" or some similar error (unfortunately, I can't see exactly the error right now, because it is on the linux side...)

are there any clues what could be the problem?

Comment: if it helps, I am using thinkpad x61t, with Fedora 9.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 9 is very old, update to the last version. I think your kernel lack the support for your ethernet card.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging if I were there:

First, try typing "ifconfig eth0 up" and see what the result is. If you don't have a connection after that, try "dhclient eth0". It might not be dhclient, I don't use Fedora and you may need to find out which DHCP client comes with your OS.

If that doesn't work, type "sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog" and enter your password. Then unplug and replug the ethernet cable, and edit your question to reflect the result.